# change my account menu position in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have created custom module which added link in Left navigation menu of My Account Page. Every things is handle By modules Layout.xml.
But My Module link is appeared at Last in position i.e after News letter Subscription. I want to add this after "My Order" Menu.

How can I do this. Please help me.

Thanks
Pravin

Answer (score 1):

In the XML file you can set your block to come before or after another block.

In the layout XML file add the following attribute to the block:

```
before="name_of_block"
```

Or:

```
after="name_of_block"
```

So your line would look something like this:

```
<block type="some/type" before="some_other_block_name" template="some/path/to/template.phtml" />
```

If you want it to come before any other block (or after every other block) use the following:

```
before="-"
```

Or:

```
after="-"
```

Comment: No I tried it.. but not working. Still the my menu link is at last of all navigation menu. here I Post my layout.xml

Comment: Did you try putting it all the way on the top (before any other block)?

Comment: version="0.1.0"><customer_account><reference name="customer_account_navigation"><action method="addLink" translate="label" module="mymodule"ifconfig="payment/module/path/active"><name>mymodule</name><path>mymodule/new/</path><label>Menu Link Title</label></action></reference></customer_account><mymodule_new_create><update handle="customer_account"/><reference name="head"><action method="setTitle"><title>Menu Title </title></action></reference><reference name="content"><block type="core/template" name="mymodule_new_create" template="mymodule/new/pathtphtml.phtml"></block>
        </reference>..

Comment: Please help me.. I want to change the position of My module menu link to After "My order" because my module is related to Order..

Comment: Sorry didn't get back earlier - try putting this code in the catalog.xml file vs is in your modules xml file (this is just to test so we can troubleshoot better)